# How to set two property value using groovy in the same time from a text file

Tags: groovy, soapui

i want to test the GetWeather webservice

```
http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx
```

I have a text file with this content:
montreal
canada
calgary
canada

My request is:

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
       <soap:Header/>
       <soap:Body>
          <web:GetWeather>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <web:CityName>${#Project#City}</web:CityName>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <web:CountryName>${#Project#Country}</web:CountryName>
          </web:GetWeather>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

My Groovy code is:

```
def f = new File("c:\\temp\\Data.txt") 
def fr= new FileReader(f)

def br = new BufferedReader(fr) 
def s = br.readLine()
def x = br.readLine() 

while(s && x !=null)
{
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("City",s)
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("Country",x)

testRunner.runTestStepByName("GetWeather - Request 1")
s = br.readLine()
x = br.readLine()
}
```

But i's not reading the file.
Any help please, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy simplifies reading lines of text files. In your case since a record consists of two lines, try this:

```
def f = new File('c:\temp\Data.txt') 
def records = f.readLines().collate(2)

records.each {
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("City",it[0])
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("Country",it[1])

    testRunner.runTestStepByName("GetWeather - Request 1")
}
```

## How it works

Lets assume the input file contains the following lines:

```
New York
USA
Istanbul
Turkey
```

Lines 1 and 2 are cities and lines 2 and 4 are countries. The statement `f.readLines()` returns a list of the file contents, like this:

```
[
    'New York',
    'USA',
    'Istanbul',
    'Turkey'
]
```

To make the data easier to work with, I turned it into a list of city and country pairs. That's what `collate(2)` does:

```
[
    ['New York', 'USA'],
    ['Istanbul', 'Turkey]'
]
```

With this new list, `each(Closure)` is used to iterate through the pairs.

```
records.each {
    // it[0] is the city
    // it[1] is the country
}
```

Comment: thank you, it's reading the txt file but how if i want to read each line, becausei have multiple lines with different city and country name.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand what you're asking. I added an explanation to my answer. Maybe it will answer your question.

Comment: now i understand, thank you for the explanation. it works for me